# Compare dates in sybase query

Tags: sql, sybase

i'm trying to make a conditional search in sybase database as below.

```
      WHERE  ( dc.TABLE.DATE_ID = DateAdd(d,-1,GetDate()))
```

The format of dc.TABLE.DATE_ID is 'Feb  6 2014'.
The scope is to search yesterday's data.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you storing dates as strings? ('Feb 6 2014')? Why? Doesn't Sybase have a `DATE` datatype?

Comment: try ! `where (cast(dc.TABLE_Id) as date=DateAdd(d,-1,getdate())`

Comment: thank you Vijaykumar but it doesn't work.
The date in the TABLE is in string format...

Comment: ok..what is the error you get...? or post the table here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way converts both value of dates to `date` type without time

```
WHERE   cast(dc.TABLE.DATE_ID  as date) = DateAdd(dd,-1,cast(GetDate() as date))
```

You can use also `datediff` function, you don't have to convert data to `date` type

```
WHERE datediff(dd,GetDate(), dc.TABLE.DATE_ID )=-1
```

---

**More infomration**

- [datediff](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X47295.htm)